# Entity Framework 6. Извлечение связанныx данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

привет есть запрос на выборку

```
 var t = context.Group.Include(g => g.Items);
```

и все работает но необходимо еще в Items включить другие данные из другой таблицы

типа такова

```
var t = context.Group.Include(g => g.Items.Include(o => o.Data));
```

Comment: Ну и? Это не сработало?

Comment: так ваще нельзя писать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установи package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ThenInclude.EF6

Затем используй:

```
var t = context.Group.Include(g => g.Items).ThenInclude(o => o.Data);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) говорит что это делается через внутренний `Select`:

```
var t = context.Group.Include(g => g.Items.Select(o => o.Data));
```

Comment: пробывал пишет не валидно так

Comment: @Санитариум кто пишет-то?

Comment: Ошибка компиляци